# Under what condition is a coordinate chart orientation-preserving

Tags: manifolds, orientation

Let $\phi: U \rightarrow O$ be a coordinate chart of an $n$-dimensional differentiable oriented manifold where $U$ is an open subset of the manifold and $O$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. If we see $\phi$ as a diffeomorphism, we can consider whether it is orientation-preserving, i.e. whether the orientations of $U$ and $O$ are consistent with each other. But since $U$ is a subset of a general manifold, how can we know whether its orientation is consistent with that of $O$? For example, if $O$ has the standard orientation, how can we know whether the orientation of $U$ is also the standard one?

Comment: Check the sign of the jacobian of the transition functions. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientability

Comment: So you need $2$ charts,  not just one.  Then on the overlap you get a diffeomorphism of $\Bbb R^n$.  An orientation is basically a choice of sign for the jacobian determinants on all the overlaps.

Comment: Sorry,  I put my foot in my mouth.   You need the jacobians to be positive.  Negative would reverse orientation.

Comment: Now a connected oriented manifold has two orientations. If we view orientations as sets of coordinate charts (following Munkres), then all the transition functions of an orientation have positive Jacobian. This is true for both orientations. So does it mean that a coordinate chart is always orientation-preserving?

Comment: If it's part of an orientation of $M$ then yes.